# new Reg() Is there a way to have a regex expression only accept whole numbers and an optional unit of measurement px?

Tags: javascript, regex

What I am testing is user input so it's always changing. I'm coding in javascript and I have came up with this..

```
var Reg = new Reg('[0-9] + [(px)?]');

var validReg = Reg.test(input);
```

It return true for numbers and true with numbers and unit px. But it also returns true for decimal numbers which I don't want and returns true with letters.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it will run. `Reg` is not the name for RegExp.

Comment: I would recommend learning RegExp syntax - for your information, the example in your question will match a single digit followed by 1 or more spaces followed by a space followed by **one of** `(`,`p`,`x`,`)` or `?` - what you possibly want is `[0-9]+(px)?` - however, that too wont be anywhere near perfect

Answer (score 1):

You're testing (or trying to) for any string containing numbers, possibly followed by `px`.

If you want the string to contain *only* those parts, anchor the regex with `^` (start of string) and `$` (end).

```
var Reg = /^[0-9]+(px)?$/;
```

will test for one or more `+` digits, followed by 0 or 1 `"px"`.

You can also use `\d` for digits, so:

```
var Reg = /^\d+(px)?$/;
```

will match

```
0
0px
110px
```

but not

```
0 etc.
0.0px
```